# Integrals of partial derivative

Tags: integration, partial-derivative, absolute-continuity

Let T be an absolutely continuous random variable and let U be an arbitrary random variable.

Then why does this equality hold: $P(t<T\leq t+s, T\leq U)=\int_t^{t+s} - \frac{\partial }{\partial v}P(T\geq v, U\geq u)|_{v=u}du$

It is not even clear to me why $P(T\geq v, U\geq u)$ would be differentiable almost everywhere with regard to $v$. I am not used to think about absolute continuity. I know this is probably very trivial so if someone would just point me towards the right theorems that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you extract the desired term you will get the following result. 
$$
P(T \geq v, U \geq u) = 1 − P((T \geq v, U \geq u)^C) = 1-((T \geq v)^C \cup (U \geq u)^C) = 1 - P((T < v) \cup (U<u)) = 1 -[P(T < v) + P(U < u) - P(T < v, U < u)] = 1 - F_T(v) + P_U(u)-F_{T,U}(v, u)
$$
You stated that T is absolutely continous, and U is arbitrary continous. Hence the result from above should also be continous.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how this rewriting solves it

Comment: I tried to examine your question "why P(T≥v,U≥u) would be differentiable almost everywhere with regard to v". Please clarify the missing points.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Why is $F_{T,U}$ is absolutely continuous ?

Comment: Because $F_{T,U}$ depends on v.

Comment: Well every function that is not absolutely continuous can be thought of as depending on $v$ in a trivial fashion

Comment: According to your statement $T$ is a continuous R.V., and $v$ belongs to $T$, which means $F_{T,U}$ should be continuous in term of v, however you're right if we examine the question regarding $u$, $F_{T,U}$ is not necessary continuous.

Comment: It follows from definition that $F_{T,U}(v, u) = \sum_{-\infty}^{v} \sum_{-\infty}^{u}f(v,u)$ In this case we said that T is countinous, hence we can substitute the first sum with an integral. $F_{T,U}(v, u) = \int_{-\infty}^{v} \sum_{-\infty}^{u}f(v,u) dv$. Hope this makes the problem clear.

Comment: I still don't see why $F_T(v)$ being absolutely continuous implies $F_{T,U}(v,u)$ being absolutely continuous in $v$. It seems like you're treating the variables as discrete which is not the case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104575/discussion-between-robertkovacs-and-caspar).